# PHP run external command and redirect when finished

Tags: php, html

I'm building a homepage where after the user have filled a form I need to run a rather long PHP script (populating my database). Therefor I'm trying to make a loading page to be displayed while the script is running and once it's done redirect to some other page.

I'm currently doing:

In form.php

```
<form method="post" action="load.php">
....
</form>
```

load.php have the loading page:

```
<?php
ob_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
...loading page here...
</html>
<?
ob_end_flush();
include 'add.php';
?>
```

Here i hope to show the page with ob_start and ob_end_flush, and the begin the script.

at the end of add.php I do

```
header('Location: redirect_to_here.php');
```

Comment: What about using AJAX?

Comment: tried but nut sure for to implement it properly

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery.post({
         url:    'http://example.com/save.php',
         data: { 'name':'name'
              },
      beforeSend:function(){
         $(".loading_msg").show();
    },
         success: function(result) {
         $(".loading_msg").hide();
                      if(result.isOk == false)
                          alert(result.message);
                  },
         async:   false
    });
```

make async false and before sending data show div and after success hide it